# Geoserver publishes geography(Point) as Point, but geography(PointZ) as Geometry

Tags: postgis, geoserver, postgresql

```
CREATE TABLE schema.table
(
    location schema."geography(Point,4326)"(1107456) NOT NULL,
    location_z schema."geography(PointZ,4326)"(1107458)
)
```

I'm trying to figure out why Geoserver recognizes a geography(Point) as Point, but sees geography(PointZ) as Geometry.

I'm using Postgres 9.5, PostGIS 2.3, and Geoserver 2.11

Comment: what do you have in the geometry metadata table for those columns? that is where GeoServer looks up the type

Comment: Are you refering to the geometry_columns table? If so, its empty, I'm only using geography. In the geography_columns table they are listed as Point and PointZ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is happening because POINTZ is not a registered geometry type in the PostGIS datastore code:
https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/master/modules/plugin/jdbc/jdbc-postgis/src/main/java/org/geotools/data/postgis/PostGISDialect.java#L86

It would be great if you could open a ticket in the GeoTools tracker:
https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/projects/GEOT/summary

Or even better, to make a pull request with a fix following these directions:
https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

Comment: It looks like they don't support PointZ yet. Thats unfortunate...

Comment: I believe it will be read and written anyways, just not recognized as a type

Comment: It's being read at least partially, I set it to a Point and PreviewLayer in geoserver shows me 2D data from the field.

Comment: Try a GetFeature request, you should see the z too

Comment: I tried http://localhost/geoserver/wfs?service=wfs&version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typeNames=cite:fdoComposite&maxFeatures=10 and got an exception. org.geotools.data.DataSourceException: An exception occurred while parsing WKB data An exception occurred while parsing WKB data Unknown WKB type 233. I get the same error when I try to populate the sql view automatically with 'Guess geometry type and srid'

Comment: As far as I know, there is no such a thing as type 233, types end in the single digit values :-) Follow my original suggestion, open a ticket, and attach a database dump to it.

Comment: Just opened a ticket with the database log. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Was doing some more research and it seems like a similar issue was reported already: https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOT-5619.